# Jenkins and Active Directory authentication

Tags: sockets, active-directory, jenkins

we're trying to set up Jenkins to automate builds. We've used Hudson for a long time but now we're migrating to Jenkins because of the Active Directory authentication support. AD-plugin is already installed:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin
As far as I can see, Jenkins is trying to connect to the AD server but gets "socket closed" error. Here's the part of the stack trace:

```
Failed to test the validity of the user name <SOMEUSER>
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: Failed to retrieve user information for <SOMEUSER>; nested exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: <SOMENAME>.<SOMENAME>:636; socket closed; remaining name 'DC=<SOMENAME>,DC=<SOMENAME>'
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:306)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:190)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:134)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.loadUserByUsername(AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.java:30)
```

I'm 100% sure, that the credentials are correct. The server that runs Jenkins is in the domain, so from this point is everything OK.
What I suppose is that Jenkins hides some error messages, therefore I'm not able to specify the problem precisely...

Comment: What version of the AD plugin are you using? Which fields have you filled in. When you fill in everything and press the "Test" button, does it succeed?

Comment: Jenkins ver. 1.465
AD plugin ver. 1.29

Fields "Domain-Name" and "Domain-Controller" are filled, but I don't see any test button. Where should it be?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, that our AD server does not support anonymous bind, so I'm not sure if (and where) the separate credentials should be given to Jenkins.

Comment: I believe you're getting that error because of the anonymous bind. I don't think the "BadCredentialsException" is your login credentials, it is your bind credentials that are getting rejected since your controller does not allow anonymous bind.

Answer (score 5):

Under "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System":

- Enable Security
- Security Realm = Active Directory
- Enter your "Domain Name"
- Click on "**Advanced**" near the right side (just under the (?) button)
- Add **Domain Controller**
- Under **Site**: add the information you need (OU=<>, DC=<>, etc) - as many as you need - ours has 5 OU(s) and 3 DC fields
- Add your bind user under **Bind DN** field (ours is something like *CN=, OU=, DC=, DC=, DC=*
- Add your bind password under **Bind Password** field

Once you've set all these (or as many as you need):
Click the **Test** button (It should be just under the Bind Password field, on the right side - close to the (?) help buttons.

Let me know if you don't see these.

**+================================================================+**

**Edit:**

For the Bind username, can you try this:

CN=,OU=SMTH,OU=SMTH,OU=SMTH,OU=SMTH,DC=SMTH,DC=SMTH,DC=SMTH

where  is the LDAP service name, or bind service name. I have not seen the

CN=SECOND_NAME\, FIRST_NAME - USER_ID

format before (not saying it's wrong, just unknown to me). So something like

CN=MY LDAP SVC Account,OU=SMTH,OU=Services,OU=Accounts,OU=my,DC=domain,DC=com

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Now I see, that the interface of Jenkins depends on locale. We used german locale until I installed the Locale Plugin few minutes ago and switched it to english. What di I see now? Right: the "Test" button and text fields that you wrote me about. Now I'll test it and immediately give you my report.

Comment: Very strange. The "Test" button is gone. Afrer I tried different configs and restarted the server a few times this button disappeared.

Comment: OK, the button and other settings reappear if I disable security, restart TomCat and enable security again.  Seems like a bug, doesn't it?

Comment: This does appear to be a bug. I would file it with the Jenkins JIRA. In the meantime, can you try running it without TomCat on a separate machine just to test the system?

Comment: I still have not tested a stand alone solution, but I've found something else. Some of our apps (Jira) use the same format for the credentials, but that does not seem to work with Jenkins

Here is a part of the stack trace:

Bad bind username or password
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: Either no such user 'CN=SECOND_NAME\, FIRST_NAME - USER_ID,OU=ExternalUsers,OU=Users,OU=SMTH,OU=SMTH,DC=SMTH,DC=SMTH' or incorrect password; nested exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: DOMAIN:636; socket closed.

Comment: See answer edit. Seemed easier to post there

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You mean, I should post additional information in the main message / question post?

Comment: No, sorry I just meant that I answered your comment, but in my answer (under the ====== line), because it was easier than posting to the comments